# Best practice for the correct user setup within a ROS docker container?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, docker, root, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[docker ros](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros) states: By default, the container runs as the root user

http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep states:
Do NOT run rosdep update with sudo. It is not required and will result in permission errors later on.

Trying to follow http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html, running in `osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full`  I am getting to `Warning: running 'rosdep update' as root is not recommended.` as below

Is there a recommended best practice for the correct user setup within a ROS docker container?

> docker run -it -v ~/catkin_wses:/root osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full

> root@0ebd9e5101b5:/# cd /root/ws_moveit-tuts/src/

> root@0ebd9e5101b5:~/ws_moveit-tuts/src# rosdep update

> reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
> Warning: running 'rosdep update' as root is not recommended.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358548/best-practice-for-the-correct-user-setup-within-a-ros-docker-container?/) by [bgraysea](https://answers.ros.org/users/56768/bgraysea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-08-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [doisyg](https://answers.ros.org/users/25266/doisyg/) on 2022-10-06**:
On the same topic, is it possible to init and update rosdep at the creation of the docker so it is available and ready for the user (regular account) ? I can do it but then the user has to use sudo before for intance 'rosdep install'. Anyway to do it without sudo, i.e. init and update rosdep in the Dockerfile as a regular user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep states: Do NOT run rosdep update with sudo. It is not required and will result in permission errors later on.

What that page writes is good advice, for *normal* usage scenarios.

Setting up a Docker image is "not" normal usage, in the sense that typically, everything in a Docker container runs as `root` (by default).

The potential issues `wiki/rosdep` is warning about are what you can run into when first running things as `root` and then switching to a regular account. But as I wrote above, that's typically not how `Dockerfile`s are written.

So I believe what you are doing is OK -- *inside a Docker image*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-03**:
But of course: if you later switch to another user in a Docker container, then you should be mindful of the recommended usage of `rosdep`.